# How to terminate a thread blocking on socket connect

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

In my android app, my activity is starting another thread for some socket network operations, and this thread is always waiting for incoming data from the socket(blocking on `read()` function in a `while` loop).

Now, when my activity gets destroyed, I would like to keep things clean, and destroy that thread. To implement this functionality, I defined a `volatile boolean` variable `isSupposedToStop` which would be initialized to `false`, and when `onStop()` gets called, it sets that `boolean` to `true`, and calls `socket.shutdownInput()` which causes the thread blocking on `read()` to throw an `IOException`, then read the `isSupposedToStop` boolean to know that it *is supposed to stop*.(if you have better ways feel free to discuss it).

So, in my `run()` implementation after connecting my socket I have:

```
sock= new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
InputStream is= sock.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer= new byte[200];
while(true){
    if(isSupposedToStop) return;
    try {
        is.read(msgSizeBuff, 0, 200);
    } catch(IOException e){
    }
    if(isSupposedToStop) return;
    //do something with the received message
}
```

in `onStop()`, I have:

```
isSupposedToStop= true;
if(sock!= null) {
    try {
        sock.shutdownInput();
        sock.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
thread.join()
```

that is working good. as when the thread is waiting for new data (blocking on `read()`), `read()` throws an `IOException` immediately when `onStop()` calls `shutdownInput()`, and control is back to the thread which reads my boolean value and exits.
but the problem is happening if `onStop()` gets called when the thread is still waiting to establish the connection (blocking on `new Socket()`) so if the host is down for example the app freezes for about 3 seconds, so do you recommend to just omit the `thread.join()` call? or is there a way to wake up this thread?

Comment: Why do you have that join call to begin with?

Comment: In native world, I'd say 'use poll/select with timeout'. In Java, seems NIO library has such capability - but I know too little of Java to elaborate any more.

Comment: @greenapps , the join call is in my `onStop()` implementation , I am calling it to make sure that other threads are destroyed before app termination, isn't it considered unsafe code if I omit that call?

Comment: @SergeyA , I don't want to turn this discussion into native world , but I would always avoid polling. In the native world I would use `pthread_cancel()` or `TerminateThread()` if asynchronous sockets weren't available

Comment: @Mike, this is your personal choice. A very strange one, of course. Polling is a wonderful tool, one of the most powerful tool in the arsenal of socket developer.

Comment: @SergeyA , well In my opinion , polling feels like waiting for the wrong thing (time to pass) and then checking if what I am really waiting for happened while I was passing time. Aside wasting CPU cycles of course. That's why whenever I have other choices than polling I go for them

Comment: No, this is not what polling is. Polling waits for certain **event** to happen, but it has a timeout. If I want to meet you on grand central, I will wait for your arrival, but only for some time. This is the same. Polling also doesn't use any CPU cycles, this is a gist of it.

Comment: @SergeyA , but in my question, since I will be blocking on the connection and checking the `isSupposedToStop` every _timeout_ msecs. that would look like waiting for my arrival on grand central for a minute, then check your mobile phone to see if I sent you message, then go back to the waiting state. wouldn't it be better if your phone ring interrupted your waiting state?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have called the `read` method you are essentially blocked - you can only escape by interrupting the thread.

```
public void test() {
    Thread socketThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    });
    // Do your stuff.
    //...
    // Time to quit - should abort any blocked reads.
    socketThread.interrupt();
}
```

Another alternative - this may not work at all - is to use the `available` method of `InputStream`.

```
public void test() throws IOException {
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        int available;
        if ((available = is.available()) > 0) {
            // Your read stuff.
            is.read(buffer, 0, available);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will, `new Socket()` throw an `IOException` when I interrupt the thread?

Comment: my question is about interrupting the thread blocked on connecting a socket, not on `read()` , I said that my code works when the thread is blocked on `read()`

Comment: @Mike - If the socket is awaiting connection then yes, it should be interrupted.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it did not interrupt when it is blocking on connect

Comment: Please note that `Socket` does not implement `InterruptibleChannel`. so `socketThread.interrupt()` will not interrupt neither `read()` nor `connect()`.
In order to benefit from `InterruptibleChannel` I would have to switch into `SocketChannel` from Java NIO.

Answer (score 1):

The new Socket isn't supposed to block networking. Not even a SYN/ACK.

Therefore you can setSOTimeout() right after construction. But you wouldn't set it to anything less than 3 seconds to be fair.

You are suggesting that it takes 3 seconds to respond to a socket.close()... So I fear it cannot get any faster, but you can try a thread.interrupt(), in case it is sitting in interruptable (non native) code.

Comment: thanks for your time, I can also use `connect(SocketAddress endpoint, int timeout)` so that the timeout is set on connection only and not on reading too. . .

Comment: as for using `thread.interrupt()` the socket I am using should implement [InterruptibleChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html), which is only available in [SocketChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) from Java NIO socket.